# high fps but slow detection of traffic signs

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision

i used about 39k images from the german traffic signs recognition benchmark dataset to train my yolov5 model. i used the command

!python train.py --img 416 --data data.yaml --cfg yolov5s.yaml --batch-size 10 --epochs 100 --name Model

to train the model

am I missing something?

when im training with smaller dataset with about 1000k images it is much faster and can detect multiple traffic signs..

pls help

Comment: what is much faster? training or detecting? If you mean `"training is much faster"` then it is normal because it uses less images to train. But after training you can save model and read it again to use it without new training.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @furas detect.py is much faster..like it can detect many traffic signs fast when i use small dataset/..

Comment: I have no idea what you have in `detect.py` so I have no idea why it faster. And I have no idea what images you have, but if code works better for smaller dataset then use smaller dataset.

Comment: yes it works faster but not that accurate..whereas witth bigger dataset it is slow but very accuracy :(